# XML examples in springdoc-openapi, swagger UI

Tags: java, springdoc-openapi-ui

I’m struggling with generation of correct XML examples in [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org/) library.

Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping
    public MonetaryValue getMonetaryValue() {
        return new MonetaryValue(BigDecimal.ONE, "EUR");
    }
}
```

Model

```java
@Schema(name="price", description = "Monetary value")
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "price")
public class MonetaryValue {
    @Schema(example = "EUR")
    @JsonProperty("cur")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "cur", isAttribute = true)
    private String currency;
    
    @Schema(example = "1.00")
    @JsonProperty("val")
    @JacksonXmlText
    private BigDecimal value;
    
    // getters, setter ...
}
```

End point called with header `Accept: application/xml` returns expected result:

```xml
<price cur="EUR">1</price>
```

However it seems that Jackson annotations are ignored in springdoc. Example shown in swagger-ui shows:

```xml
<value>
    <cur>EUR</cur>
    <val>1</val>
</value>
```

I have also tried to add JAXB annotations.

```java
@Schema(name="price", description = "Monetary value")
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "price")
public class MonetaryValue {
        @Schema(example = "EUR")
    @JsonProperty("cur")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "cur", isAttribute = true)
    @XmlAttribute(name = "cur")
    private String currency;
    
    @Schema(example = "1.00")
    @JsonProperty("val")
    @JacksonXmlText
    @XmlValue
    private BigDecimal value;   
    // getters, setter ...
}
```

It partly helped, attribute is shown correctly, but `@XmlValue` annotation seems to be is ignored. Value is shown in sub-element `val` instead of element's text.

```xml
<value cur="EUR">
    <val>1</val>
</value>
```

JSON examples work without any problem.

[Demo project on GitHub](https://github.com/ales77/springdoc-openapi-wrong-xml-example).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the OpenAPI spec.

```xml
<value cur="EUR">1</value>
```

The XML structure you want to achieve is not supported by OpenAPI.

There is a GitHub issue tracking this: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/630